# What is the difference between Vayomer and Vayomar?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash

In Chumash, sometimes it says vayomer, but other times it says vayomar. What is the difference? Don't they both just mean "he said"?

Answer (score 4):

As you noted in your comment, at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8).org, וַיֹּאמַר is the [pausal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pausa) form of וַיֹּאמֶר.  In use in the bible, generally coming off of a previous introductory verb, it seems to be more reasonably translated as "*saying:*" akin to "לאמר" (or "*and said:*") rather than as "And he said..." or "He said...".  See, e.g., [Job 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.1.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in which וַיֹּאמַר may be interpreted just by using quotation marks:

> **וַיֹּ֧אמֶר** ה' אֶל־הַשָּׂטָ֖ן מֵאַ֣יִן תָּבֹ֑א וַיַּ֨עַן הַשָּׂטָ֤ן אֶת־ה' **וַיֹּאמַ֔ר** מִשּׁ֣וּט בָּאָ֔רֶץ וּמֵֽהִתְהַלֵּ֖ךְ בָּֽהּ׃
>
> The LORD **said** to the Adversary, “Where have you been?” The Adversary answered the LORD, **“** I have been roaming all over the earth. **”**